# React Hooks | useEffect : why is there a dependency lint error for one but not both of these hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

If state.zip changes, 'getLocations' is called again.  No warnings.  After 'locations' or 'testFilter' are updated filterSearchLocations is called to set the state of 'searchLocations' which are displayed to the user.  Following ESLint error:

```
 Line 91:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'filterSearchLocations'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Why is this warning getting thrown on the second useEffect but not the first?

```
  const getLocations = async () => {
    setFetching(true);
    try {
      const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/common/locations');
      dispatch({ type: SET_ALL_LOCATIONS, payload: res.data });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      dispatch({ type: SET_ERROR, payload: e.message });
    } finally {
      setFetching(false);
    }
  };

  const filterSearchLocations = () => {
    const searchLocations =
      Object.keys(state.testFilter).length === 0
        ? state.allLocations
        : state.allLocations.filter((location) => {
            for (let [test] of Object.entries(state.testFilter)) {
              if (state.testFilter[test] && location.tests.indexOf(test) === -1)
                return false;
            }
            return true;
          });
    dispatch({ type: SET_SEARCH_LOCATIONS, payload: searchLocations });
  };

  // get distances
  useEffect(() => {
    getLocations();
  }, [state.zip]);

  // filter search locations
  useEffect(() => {
    filterSearchLocations();
  }, [state.allLocations, state.testFilter]);
```

Comment: This happens because `filterSearchLocations` is using the `state` constant inside its body. The linter does not care which specific items you use inside it, only that it might be accessing parts that are not in the dependency list. You could wrap the `filterSearchLocations` in a `useCallback` with the correct dependencies there and set the dependencies of the `useEffect` to just `filterSearchLocations`